# Hybris Smartedit loading forever on "we are preparing the page to be edited on smartedit"

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

[image]When I open a Apparel UK Staged site on Hybris 6.2 Smartedit its giving a message "We are preparing the page to be edited on Smartedit" and it keeps loading forever". The server messages are also not helpful.

smarteditwebservices and smarteditaddon extentions are in my localextensions.xml file.

Using Google Chrome and Windows 10.

Has anyone else faced a issue like this?

[image]

Comment: Could you share the console output, please? Without it might be very hard to guess.

Comment: added the pictures of console, please let me know if you know the fix. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the smartedit addon on your storefront. Also check in browser console if you are getting any js related error, which might cause from cross-origin.